# Spring dynamicly inject a service based on its generic type

Tags: java, spring, generics, dependency-injection

I have a service class named `ChildService<B>` that extends another service class named `ParentService<T extends A>`.

Now `B` is a subtype of `A`.

And `ChildService<B>` is a subtype of `ParentService<T extends A>`

In fact I have a lot of classes similar to `B` (shares the same super type `A`) and it is the same with the services.

Now I have a Class That looks this way :

```
public class Controller {
    @Resource
    private ParentService<A> service;

    public void someMethod(A a){
    //Here I want to use the service based on the type of A , if it is B
    // then i want to use ChildService and so on 
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have nearly 100 class like B, and Honestly injecting all the services and do an isntance of test or repeat the same logic 100 time feels that I am doing something wrong.
Is there another way or a rightful way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm struggling to see your inheritance hierarchy and how it all comes together with the services. Please provide a simple example.